# Error during deployment: Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the function in SSAS

Tags: ssas

I am creating a new calculation in SSAS, to calculate avg value.

I have already two measure created:

1. Sum of Risk Score as `[Measures].[Risk Score]`
2. Total Count as `[Measures].[VM Result Table Count]`

And in the expression tab I have written the following expression.

```
[Measures].[Risk Score] / [Measures].[VM Result Table Count]
```

Now, when I deploy the SSAS project, I get the following error:
   `"MdxScript(VMCube) (10, 22) Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the`  function."

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Try setting the calculation to NULL instead and see if the error is related to to it. With out seeing more code around the calc tt seems as though there is another error I would say.

Comment: Tried with NULL. The deployment was successful. Seems to be some other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated members belong to a measure group of your choice. Maybe the values belong to different measure groups and don't 'see' each other. But as Preet Sangha stated... without knowing more that is only a wild guess.

Comment: Both the measures belong to same measure group.